Linear Transformation with Differentiation Operator
The mapping $T : \Bbb P_2 \rightarrow \Bbb P_2$ defined by
$$T(a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2)= a_1 +2a_2t $$ is a linear transformation. You will recognize $T$ to be the differentiation operator. 
(a) Find the $\beta$ -matrix for $T$ , where $\beta$ is the basis {$1,t,t^2$}. Denote the matrix by $M$. 
(b) Let p $\in$ $\Bbb P_2$ with p$(t)=3t^2+5$. Compute $M[$p$]_\beta$.
I am completely lost here. My notes from lecture have no mention of computing linear transformation with polynomials, let alone differentiation operator. I understand to some extent I need to find a matrix that when multiplied, results in the derivative of the input. I realize the answer to (b) will simply be $6t$ but I don't know how to express this in matrix form. I was thinking the $\beta$-matrix could possibly contain a $\frac 1t$ term to simulate a derivative.

Don't let the fact they're polynomials confuse you, the vector is the coefficients. The monomial terms just tell you which coordinate they are. So this is basically $T(a_0,a_1,a_2) =a_1+2a_2$ once you scrub the monomials. The matrix won't contain any $t$ terms at all.

We are looking for a matrix that when multiplied into polynomial $\pmatrix {c,bt,at^2}$ returns the derivative of that polynomial.
$M = \pmatrix {0&1&0\\0&0&2\\0&0&0}$ will do the trick.
Note that the first column is the derivative $1,$ the second column is the derivative of $t,$ and the 3rd column is the derivative of $t^2$
$\pmatrix {0&1&0\\0&0&2\\0&0&0}\pmatrix {c\\bt\\at^2}  = \pmatrix{b\\2at\\0}$
It is more common to not show the $t's$ in the vector representing the polynomial, but at this stage, it is a little bit more clear.
I will leave part b).
